# Search for products based on criteria

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, search

The method must search `Product`s found by criteria and store them in `@products`.

The criteria are as follows:

- If the user enters something in `text_field` (`:search_keywords`) then the product's name needs to be matched with that word
- If the user specifies `product_type` (`:product[:type]`) then all the found products must be of that type.

```
def search
  if params[:search_keywords] && params[:search_keywords] != ""
    @products = Product.where("name LIKE '%" + params[:search_keywords] + "%'")
    if params[:product] && params[:product][:type] && params[:product][:type] != ""
      @products = Product.where("name LIKE '%" + params[:search_keywords] + "%' AND product_type_id = " + params[:product][:type])
    end
  else
    if params[:product] && params[:product][:type] && params[:product][:type] != ""
      @products = Product.find_all_by_product_type_id(params[:product][:type])
    else
      @products = Product.all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that the way you build your queries is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection. Please see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html under the conditions section on how to safely build queries.

Answer (score 8):

Try to use scopes, its a lot nicer

```
def search
  @products = Products.scoped
  if !params[:search_keywords].blank?
    @products = @products.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search_keywords]}%")
  end
  if !params[:product].try(:[], :type).blank?
    @products = @products.where(:product_type_id => params[:product][:type])
  end
  @products # maybe @products.all if realy needed
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I've seen many Railers' codes tempt to shove many logic in View and Controller. Allow me to add these important emphases:

1. **Skinny Controller Fat Model** which is one of *The Elegant Rails Way principles*.
2. And **Testing**.

Here I have **products_controller.rb** file inside **app/controllers** directory that contains this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @products = Product.search(params)
  end
end
```

I put the logic inside the Model. Here is my **product.rb** file inside **app/models** directory:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :nm, lambda { |n| where "name LIKE ?", '%' + n + '%' }
  scope :criteria, lambda { |n, type| nm(n).where type_id: type }

  def self.search(opts={})
    return all if opts.empty?
    return nm(opts[:search_keywords]) unless opts[:search_keywords].nil?
    return criteria(opts[:name], opts[:type]) if opts[:product].try(:[], :type).empty?
  end
end
```

You could also try to experiment *Dynamic Scope Construction* to improve Product Model code above. I haven't tried it successfully **AND** efficiently here, let me know if anyone can make it better, anyway.

And **Testing**. You can also test your app using [RSpec](http://apidock.com/rspec), [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/), Ruby Selenium, Watir, or any other Test for Ruby Environment, but here I'll only show you how to do it using Ruby Unit Test. Here is my **product_test.rb** inside **test/unit** directory:

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'product'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :products

  def test_nm
    assert_equal Product.nm("Pick").first.name, products(:pickaxe).name
  end

  def test_criteria
    assert_equal Product.criteria("Bach", 2).first.name, products(:bach).name
  end

  def test_search
    assert_equal Product.search(:search_keywords => "Pick").first.name, 
                 products(:pickaxe).name
    assert_equal Product.search(:search_keywords => "Pick", :type => 1).first.name, 
                 products(:pickaxe).name
    assert_equal Product.search.size, Product.count
  end
end
```

And its related fixture. Here is my **products.yml** file inside **test/fixtures** directory:

```
pickaxe:
  name: Pickaxe 3
  type_id: 1

bach:
  name: Bach
  type_id: 2

lotr:
  name: LOTR
  type_id: 3
```

And for controller testing, here is my **products_controller_test.rb** file inside **test/functional** directory:

```
require 'test_helper'
require "products_controller"

class ProductsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :products

  test "should get search" do
    get :search, :search_keywords => 'Pick', :product => { :type => '1' }
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:products)
  end
end
```

Let's go test them. I use:

```
. ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-darwin9.8.0]
. rails -v
Rails 3.0.9
```

Here is my test's result:

```
. rake test
(in /Users/arie/se/tester)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "products_id_seq" for serial column "products.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "products_pkey" for table "products"
Loaded suite /opt/experiment/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
...
Finished in 0.237899 seconds.

3 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 54809
Loaded suite /opt/experiment/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.
Finished in 0.330431 seconds.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 25681
```

Alright! Worked like a charm! 0 errors for both unit (for model) and functional (for controller) tests. I also tested it from my browser and it worked.

[You can also download my copy files here](http://ifile.it/ep6hyzb).

Links:

1. [Testing Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)
2. [Beginning with Cucumber RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber)
3. [Active Record Query Interface 3.0](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface)
4. [The Skinny on Scopes (Formerly named_scope)](http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use blank?
2. You need user parameters in SQL query.
3. Maybe you need escaping character `%` in `search_keywords`.

```
def search
    keywords_blank = params[:search_keywords].blank?
    type_blank = params[:product] && !params[:product][:type].blank?

    @products = if keywords_blank && type_blank
      Product.all
    elsif keywords_blank
      Product.find_all_by_product_type_id(params[:product][:type])
    elsif type_blank
      Product.find(:all, :conditions => ["name LIKE :name", :name => "%#{params[:search_keywords]}%"])
    else
      Product.find(:conditions => ["name LIKE :name AND product_type_id = :type", {:name => "%#{params[:search_keywords]}%", :type => params[:product][:type]}])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of scopes to simplify the code. Also, you can take advantage of some handy Ruby/ActiveSupport methods and conventions to avoid if conditions.

```
def search
  @products = Product.scoped
  @products = @products.search_by_name(params[:search_keywords])
  @products = @products.search_by_type(params[:product][:type] rescue nil)
  # in your view
  # @products.all
end 

class Product

  def self.search_by_name(value)
    if value.present?
      where("name LIKE ?", "%#{value}%")
    else
      self
    end
  end

  def self.search_by_type(value)
    if value.present?
      where(:product_type_id => value)
    else
      self
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Bert Goethals, Arie and Simone Carletti's answers - my solution would have a touch of each:

in your controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def search
    keywords = params[:search_keywords]
    type_id = params[:product].try(:[],:type)
    @products = Product.search({:type_id => type_id, :keywords => keywords})
  end

end
```

in your model

```
  def self.search(options={})
    keywords = options[:keywords]
    type_id = options[:type_id]

    products = Product.scoped
    products = products.where("name like ?","%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present? 
    products = products.where(:type_id => type_id) if type_id.present?
    products
  end
```

I could go with scopes but only if the scope will be used from more than one spot, otherwise the code is small enough to be understandable and organized without them.